# How to scrape text from a page in a HTTPWebRequest?

Tags: c#, web-scraping

how would one scrape certain text from a website using a HTTPWebRequest?

I have this code but it only works with HREF, how can I make it to work with text?

Heres the code to scrape I have:

```
// setup variables for scraping
int startPos = 0, endPos = 0, length = 0;
string tempString = "";

// do the scraping
startPos = html.IndexOf("");
endPos = html.IndexOf(">", startPos);
length = endPos - startPos;
tempString = html.Substring(startPos, length);
```

For example if a page had this code how can I make it only scrape the1ddiariesareback?:

```
<s class="hash">#</s><b>the1ddiariesareback</b></span></a>
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to download and parse the HTML for you.

You can query the object model using XPath or LINQ to XML syntax.

Comment: What if I dont know XPath, LINQ, or XMl?

Comment: Which ones easier XPath or the other one?

Comment: @user1017524 - XPath is not difficult, but LINQ has more application.

Comment: So XPaths learning curve isnt that bad? I should get the hang of it in an hour or two?

Comment: @user1017524 - The basics. If you understand paths in hierarchical filesystems you should be able to grasp the basic syntax quickly.

Comment: I didnt understand a single thing you said from: "If you understand" :). I guess I have a lot of learning to do